# HQL query minus some specific fields

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

It is possible with a HQL query to retrieve every fields EXCEPT one.

Something like :

```
session.get(entityClass, id).withoutThisField(fieldNotDesired)
```

***Example*** : I have a class `Picture(int id, String name , byte[] file)`.

I want to retrieve all pictures except the field file.

I know I can do it if I precise the fields wanted but I don't want to update my query every time a new field is added.

I know if the field is a blob, it will be retrieve only if necessary. It is not my case.
And bytecode instrumentation to precise a field `lazy=true` doesn't work, I have weird exceptions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an inherited class.

Have the PictureFile be a subclass of Picture that adds just the one field file.

In your example, you can just get the Picture. When you do need to file blob, get the PictureFile.

I find myself frequently creating several alternative mappings for entities, based on specific needs like this.